# How to add a line break hint in an Android app name

Tags: android

I have an app name that consists of a single word, but it happens to be a slightly long word (14 characters). In the Launcher on my phone, this name is longer then the allocated space so Android breaks the word after the last character that still fits on the first line, which is the wrong place. How can I hint Android where it should add the line break in the app name in case it ever needs to be broken to wrap it over multiple lines?

A workaround would be to just add a space in the word so Android will wrap it there. But this would spell the word incorrect and is inconsistent with the branding of the app, which is unacceptable. The same holds for adding a hyphen on the wrapping position.

Another possible solution would be to add a soft hyphen (U+00AD) on the wrapping position, but Android doesn't seem to care for that. It always displays the hyphen (so it's not treated as soft) and it doesn't use the hyphen as the wrapping position either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Quick summary of the correct answer to the "Zero-width line breaking space for Android" question: the android linebreaking algorithm does not support this feature

Comment: Since this was marked as a duplicate, I can't add an outright answer, but I'll just comment here that adding the HTML entity `&#8203` to your `app_name` string resource will insert a zero-width space which is handled as expected when the app name is rendered in Android 5.x. I have not tried it on earlier Android versions, however, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Use \n in your String or String Reference in XML. That should do the trick!

Comment: `\n` is a hard break, but the OP asks about line break hint.